# Java OpenGL Perspective matrix not working

Tags: opengl, java, matrix, perspective

I'm trying to render a simple triangle with OpenGL in Java using LWJGL3. 
Everything is working great, but the projection matrix (perspective) is not working. In C++ I just used to apply the `glm::perspective()` method which works just great. But in Java, I implemented it myself since there are no libraries like GLM handling it.
So here the code for the perspective in Java :

```
public mat4 perspective(float fov, float aspectRatio, float zNear, float zFar){
    mat4 perspective = new mat4();

    float halfTanFov = (float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov/2));
    float range = zNear - zFar; 

    perspective.m00 = 1f / halfTanFov * aspectRatio; 
    perspective.m11 = 1f / halfTanFov ;  
    perspective.m22 = - (zFar - zNear) / range; 
    perspective.m23 = -1; 
    perspective.m32 = (2f * zFar * zNear) / range; 

    return perspective; 
}
```

Of course I tested this multiplication and a compared a result with my TI output, and it worked great. 
Other information, the default `constructor` for the `mat4` class is putting all the values to 0. 
here is the code :

```
public void setZero(){
    m00 = 0; m01 = 0; m02 = 0; m03 = 0;
    m10 = 0; m11 = 0; m12 = 0; m13 = 0;
    m20 = 0; m21 = 0; m22 = 0; m23 = 0;
    m30 = 0; m31 = 0; m32 = 0; m33 = 0; 
}
```

the `viewMatrix()` in the other hand is working great. It's a simple implementation of the `lookAt()` method. 
So when it's `lookAtMatrix * modelMatrix * position` where the `position` is a `vec4` the result is good. 
But when I try to add the projection matrix for the MVP : `perspective * lookatMatrix * model * position` the result is nothing. 
Here where I do it in the code :

```
public mat4 getViewProjection() {
    mViewProjection = MatrixTransform.getInstance().lookAt(mPosition, mPosition.add(mDirection), mUp);
    return mViewProjection;
}
public mat4 getMVP(mat4 model){
    return mPerspective.mult(getViewProjection()).mult(model);
}
```

And here is my simple GLSL shader (for the vertex shader ) :

```
#version 430

layout(location=0) in vec3 position; 
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1); 
}
```

I tried other implementation of the perspective without success, so I guess my mistake is somewhere else, but sadly enough, I can't figure out where. If someone could help, it'd be great ! thank you. 
If you other informations, please ask me and I'll post it.

**EDIT :** 
Here is how I put a mat4 into a uniform :

```
    public void uniform(String variableName, mat4 matrix){
            int loc = glGetUniformLocation(mId, variableName);
            FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
            matrix.putIntoBuffer(buffer);
            buffer.flip();
            glUniformMatrix4(loc, false, buffer);
    }
```

and the method `putIntoBuffer()` :

```
public void putIntoBuffer(FloatBuffer buffer){
    buffer.put(m00);
    buffer.put(m01);
    buffer.put(m02);
    buffer.put(m03);

    buffer.put(m10);
    buffer.put(m11);
    buffer.put(m12);
    buffer.put(m13);

    buffer.put(m20);
    buffer.put(m21);
    buffer.put(m22);
    buffer.put(m23);

    buffer.put(m30);
    buffer.put(m31);
    buffer.put(m32);
    buffer.put(m33);
 }
```

Comment: I use DX so I'm spoiled a bit with wrapper-classes-o-plenty. I have wasted more than a "few" hours fixing problems that didn't exist because I forgot the Row-Major vs. Column-Major difference (i.e. have to Transpose matrices when uploading). When it wasn't that, I was mixing Left and Right-handed matrix methods. These might not apply to your gl setup at all, but I thought I'd offer you something to double-check.

Comment: Also, during these "WTF ARE YOU DOING GPU?!??!" moments, I start by disabling culling. Culling was hiding the fact that I'd sent RH primitives through LH matrices or vice-versa. The matrices were always fine.

Comment: Just noticed this is a year old... "Modified by community" recently, #3 on the front page, yet.... was it??? This appears to be abandoned; was it "bumped" or something?

Comment: @Jon If you don't know by now, the 'Community' 'touches' a question once per hour to try and promote it. It's usually an old-ish question with one or two answer that has no accepted answer. I believe it's done in order for new users to answer, so that the question can eventually get an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Other information, the default constructor for the mat4 class is putting all the values to 0

This is incorrect.  Your default matrix should be the identity matrix instead; i.e:

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you, and yes it should be set to identity by default. But could you explain how it would solve my problem ? All the number on the main diagonal get a new value in the `perspective()` method (only the 3,3 value didn't, but I just give it 1 and nothing changed), and the lookAt method reset all the values of the matrix. Can you explain further ? thank you.

Comment: It’s not particularly “incorrect”. It’s probably preferable to have an explicit constructor `mat4(1.0)` for this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LWJGL examples.

This one could help you: 
https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/master/src/org/lwjgl/demo/opengl/shadow/ShadowMappingDemo.java